# Swift 3 equivalent of setting a value to a dictionary key if the key doesn't exist

Tags: swift

In JavaScript, I'd do something like the following if a key doesn't exist in my "Dictionary"  (technically a javaScript object):

```
foo = foo || {}

if ( ! foo.someArg ) 
  foo.someArg = "I'm not set if I wasn't already";
```

So my function in Swift 3 is something as trivial as:

```
func someFunc(foo: Dictionary<String, Any>)
```

The value is set to type `Any` because it can be of type `String` or `Int`. What I want to do is see if `foo` has the key `someArg` set and if it doesn't, set it to a sane default.

```
if foo["someArg"] == null
  // doesn't seem to be the swift way to do it
```

What's the common idiom for achieving this with Swift 3?

Comment: On a side note, having dictionaries of heterogenous types is generally a bad idea in Swift. There's almost always a better way to design the data structure, which better enforces type safety.

Comment: Are you looking for the Swift equivalent of `foo = foo || {}` or of `if ( ! foo.someArg ) foo.someArg = "..."` ?

Comment: Also another side note, you want to check for `nil`, not `null`.

Comment: @Alexander that's a concern. Now I have to look into a better way to design this.

Comment: @randombits We can help with that if you give us some more detail to work with. In 99% of cases that I see people using heterogeneous dictionaries, they use them to store values associated with a fixed set of keys. That is the deal use case of structs and classes, which are **much** more preferable.

Comment: @Alexander thank you so much. I'll leave this question open and accept an answer to help someone else, but a struct actually makes a lot of sense here in what I'm doing.

Comment: @randombits More performant access to members, type safety, the ability to conform to protocols and have instance methods... certainly a good choice.

Comment: You should listen to Martin's comment and elaborate on exactly what your question is.

Comment: In JS there is little difference between an object and a dictionary, in most other languages the difference is crucial. Don't use dictionaries to represent objects.

Comment: @Sulthan ^ Exactly. Don't write Javascript in a language that isn't Javascript :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [The Nil-Coalescing Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72)

```
foo["someArg"] = foo["someArg"] ?? "default value"
```

> The *nil-coalescing operator* (`a ?? b`) unwraps an optional `a` if it contains a value, or returns a default value `b` if a is `nil`.

If copy-on-write performance is a concern, just use an `if` statement:

```
if foo["someArg"] == nil { foo["someArg"] = "default value" }
```

Comment: But this assigns a value in each case, even if the key was present before.

Comment: I don't know if it is a performance issue, but your first solution would trigger a property observer in any case, and the second one only if a new value is assigned. So they are different.

Comment: @MartinR Interesting point, that didn't occur to me. Though to be fair, it's pretty critical you compare new and old value to make sure there's actually change. You shouldn't just *hope* that consumers of your API only ever do assignment for changed values

Comment: @Hamish Now what happens if there is already another dict referencing the same backing storage? If the CoW works naively by doing a copy anytime a new value is assigned to a key through the subscript, then this would cause always cause a copy. If they're smart, they would check to ensure the old and new values are different, and make a copy if there is actually a change

Comment: @Alexander Ah whoops, never mind me – thought you were referring to the `??` on a `Dictionary` with a unique referenced buffer.

Answer (score 0):

For the joy of different alternatives: you can make use of the fact that *the result* of an assignment is an empty tuple `()` to perform an inline `"default value"` assignment only if the given key(-value) `"someArg"` does not exist.

```
foo["someArg"].map{ _ in () } ?? (foo["someArg"] = "default value")
```

This approach, much like the explicit `if` statement, does not suffer from an unnecessary assignment in case the given key(-value) actually does exist. Comparing the semantics of this solution with the explicit `if` statement one, however, ....